# MFC Debug Assertion Failed (filecore.cpp LINE 302)

Tags: debugging, mfc, assertion

I am learning one by one by watching the image processing program using MFC.
If you load an image file stored in a PC for image processing, an error occurs as shown below.
Is the cause far?

The error logs generated by the debugger in visual studio are shown below.

```
'Image_Tool.exe'(Win32): 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\xmllite.dll' unloaded
0x161c thread is closed (code : 0 (0x0)).
'Image_Tool.exe'(Win32): 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WMASF.DLL' unloaded
'Image_Tool.exe'(Win32): 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfperfhelper.dll' unloaded
'Image_Tool.exe'(Win32): 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WMVCORE.DLL' unloaded
'Image_Tool.exe'(Win32): 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\audiodev.dll' unloaded
'Image_Tool.exe'(Win32): 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wpdshext.dll' unloaded
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mfc120ud.dll
File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\filecore.cpp
Line: 302
```

In Visual Studio I was informed of the location where the program ended

```cpp
void CImage_ToolDoc::OnReverseImg()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
        {
            m_OutImg[i][j] = 255 - m_InImg[i][j];
        }
        UpdateAllViews(NULL);
    }
}

void CImage_ToolDoc::TwoImgLoad()
{
    CFile file;
    CFileDialog opendlg1(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, NULL); 
    if (opendlg1.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        file.Open(opendlg1.GetFileName(), CFile::modeRead);
        file.Read(m_InImg1, sizeof(m_InImg1));
        file.Close();
    }

    CFileDialog opendlg2(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, NULL);
    if (opendlg2.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        file.Open(opendlg2.GetFileName(), CFile::modeRead);
        file.Read(m_InImg2, sizeof(m_InImg2));
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Debug assertion dialog:

[image: Debug assertion dialog]

Comment: *"Press Retry to debug the application"* - You should. Doing so will present you with a full callstack at the time the debug assertion failed.

Comment: When I turn on the debugger in Visual Studio, ASSERT (m_hFile! = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE); The program is interrupted at. What should we do now?

Comment: Clearly, your call to `file.Open()` failed. Presumably, because you have enabled `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class#getfilename) has instructions on how to properly deal with this situation. There is no conceivable reason to ever ignore the documentation.

Comment: Check what `opendlg1.GetFileName()` actually returns and check if your call to [`CFile::Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b2eb5757-d499-4e67-b044-dd7d1abaa0f8.aspx#cfile__open) fails.

Comment: After running the debugger, I reviewed opendlg1. I noticed that [CFileDialog] is NULL. {hWnd = 0x00000000 <NULL>} mfc120ud.dll! CFileDialog

But .. GetFileName () is m_szFileName 0x0075eb10 L "C: \\ Users \\ jy \\ Downloads \\ a + .raw" wchar_t [260]

This function was returning the file path of a + .raw selected from my PC.


What should I do now?

Comment: I linked to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class#getfilename) previously, that tells you to **not** call `GetFileName` if you have the `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` flag set. If you continue to ignore documentation, your best bet would be to hire a developer instead. MFC is a challenging framework. You cannot hope to use it proficiently without knowing the Windows API and C++ intimately.